# Phonegap:Image Gallery loads very slowly

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, android-sdcard

I am reading images from an sd card and displaying it in the gallery in my phonegap application. 
I have two folders from which I am reading the contents. One is a synched folder and an unsynched folder.
The code is as follows:

```
 listGalleryContents(synchedsdcardfolder, function() {
    listGalleryContents(unsynchedsdcardfolder, function() {
        showGalleryPage();
    });
 });




function listGalleryContents(directoryEntry, onComplete) {
var directoryReader = directoryEntry.createReader();
directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries) { // success get files and folders
    for(var i=0; i<entries.length; ++i) {
        if(entries[i].name.indexOf(".") > 0 && entries[i].isFile) {
            imagesArray.push(entries[i].fullPath);
        }
    }
    onComplete();
} , function(error){ 
    alert("Error: = " + error.code);
});
}
```

The problem comes when I have too many images to read from the sd card. 
 When i click on gallery view, it takes a lot of time to load the images. 
 Is there any way to make it more responsive and improve the performance please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is single threaded and hence callbacks will fire in the same main thread which blocks the UI. Try changing your code to this:

```
listGalleryContents(synchedsdcardfolder, loadUnSyncedFolder);

function loadUnSynchedFolder() {
   setTimeout(function() {
       listGalleryContents(unsynchedsdcardfolder, allFoldersLoaded);
   }, 0);
}

function allFoldersLoaded() {
   setTimeout(showGalleryPage, 0);
}

function listGalleryContents(directoryEntry, onComplete) {
var successCallback = onComplete;
var directoryReader = directoryEntry.createReader();
directoryReader.readEntries(
     function(entries) { readSuccess(entries, successCallback); } , 
     function(error){ 
        alert("Error: = " + error.code);
     });
}

function readSuccess(entries, onComplete) { // success get files and folders
    var i = 0, length = entries.length; 
    for(; i < length ; ++i) { // why are you using ++i and not i++ ??
        if(entries[i].name.indexOf(".") > 0 && entries[i].isFile) {
            imagesArray.push(entries[i].fullPath);
        }
    }
    onComplete();
   }
}
```

**I have not tested this code. You may have to make minor modifications to it if you see errors.**

Comment: Thanks a lot.The performance seems to have improved a lot.I have a couple of doubts pls.Query 1:Can we not have setTimeout inside the listGalleryContents();something like threads so that i populate the imagesArray with a few values and call the onComplete();  And then the rest of the population happens in the background?Query 2:In what way is it useful to have setTimeout(function(), 0); inside the loadUnSynchedFolder() and allFoldersLoaded() since there is only one method called in it.Is it that though the control comes back to allFoldersLoaded() it will not call the showGalleryPage();? Thanks

Comment: I will answer your "Query 2" first: setTimeout(function() {}, 0) allows the browser to execute the queued operation when "it can" and does not force it execute within a certain time.

Comment: As for your "Query 1": it is good practice to avoid closures that's why I took out the success handler in to its own function. The success handler will be called in the most common case and that's why I left the error handler closure (inline) as-is.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot for explaining in great detail. Appreciate it a lot.

Comment: I implemented this and shared it with my client. Since there is some latency, he is not satisfied:(. Is there something I could do so there there is no waiting period.I have my gallery view split across pages displaying a certain amount of images in a page. When I click on next to go to the next gallery page, sometimes it doesn't respond for about 6 seconds because it will be waiting for the imagesArray to be populated. You think i could do something to make it more efficient?Thanks

Comment: I looked up on the net and found the following:There is always a 300ms delay when a button is clicked.It waits for that duration to see if its just a click or a double click.To overcome that you can use fastclick (https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons) . This makes the buttons more responsive. and page loading will be faster comparitively.

Comment: Yes mobile browsers have a ~150ms delay depending on the browser implementation which is supposed to be "help users" but this creates a problem for mobile html5 apps. Instead of binding to "click" events, you will need to bind to touch events. Look at libraries like ZeptoJS, QuoJS that provide easy to bind touch handlers like tap, longtap, swipeRight, swipeLeft etc.